# Why is np.where() faster on copies of array slices rather than views on the original array?

Tags: python, numpy

I was profiling some of my code and found a result that surprised me with `np.where()`. I wanted to use `where()` on a slice of my array (knowing that a good portion of the 2D array was irrelevant for my search) and found it to be a bottleneck in my code. As a test, I created a new 2D array as a copy of that slice and tested the speed of `where()`. It turned out that it ran appreciably faster. In my actual case, the speed increase was really significant, but I think this test code still demonstrates my findings:

```
import numpy as np

def where_on_view(arr):
    new_arr = np.where(arr[:, 25:75] == 5, arr[:, 25:75], np.NaN)

def where_on_copy(arr):
    copied_arr = arr[:, 25:75].copy()
    new_arr = np.where(copied_arr == 5, copied_arr, np.NaN)

arr = np.random.choice(np.arange(10), 1000000).reshape(1000, 1000)
```

And the `timeit` results:

```
%timeit where_on_view(arr)
398 µs ± 2.82 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit where_on_copy(arr)
295 µs ± 6.07 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Since both methods return a new array, I'm unclear on how taking a full copy of the slice beforehand is able to speed up `np.where()` to this degree. I've also done a couple of sanity checks that confirm:

1. They both return the same result in this case.
2. `where()` search is actually restricted to the slice and not checking the whole array then filtering the output.

Here:

```
# Sanity check that they do give the same output

test_arr = np.random.choice(np.arange(3), 25).reshape(5, 5)
test_arr_copy = test_arr[:, 1:3].copy()

print("No copy")
print(np.where(test_arr[:, 1:3] == 2, test_arr[:, 1:3], np.NaN))
print("With copy")
print(np.where(test_arr_copy == 2, test_arr_copy, np.NaN))

# Sanity check that it doesn't search the whole array

def where_on_full_array(arr):
    new_arr = np.where(arr == 5, arr, np.NaN)

#%timeit where_on_full_array(arr)
#7.54 ms ± 47.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

I'm curious about where the added overhead comes from in this case?

Comment: Strides for the slice is (8000,8), same as for the original.  Strides for the copy is (400,8).  So the jump from one row to the next is much smaller.  While it's searching the same number of elements, the `copy` layout is more compact, and presumably faster to traverse for some combination of paging and caching factors.

Comment: @hpaulj I speak from ignorance on this but how is that overhead avoided when making a copy of the values?

Comment: It's only incurred once (instead of multiple times), but even comparing `arr[:, 25:75].copy() == 5` and `arr[:, 25:75] == 5`, the copy wins, and it really shouldn't with a good implementation. The performance impact of multidimensional arrays and noncontiguous arrays is just really weird with NumPy, and I've always wanted to get a good enough understanding of how all the layers of indirection and buffering fit together to fully understand it.

Comment: @user2357112 if you and hpaulj can't give a definitive answer on this then I assume this question will remain in limbo. In any case, you've both given me assurance that I'm not going mad that this result is not intuitive, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are a few source snippets that at least partially explain the observation. I'm not looking into `where` since the difference appears to be created before. Instead I'm looking at `ufuncs` in general.

### Basic functioning of ufuncs

Ignoring for the moment some special casing ufuncs are computed by a potentially optimized innermost 1D loop inside an outer loop that covers the other dimensions.

The outer loop is comparatively expensive, it uses a numpy `nditer`, so has to set this up and for each iteration call `iternext` which is a function pointer, so no inlining.

By comparison, the inner loop is a simple `C` loop.

### Strided ufunc evaluation has significant overhead

from numpy/core/src/private/lowlevel_strided_loops.h which is included by numpy/core/src/umath/ufunc_object.c

```
/*
 *            TRIVIAL ITERATION
 *
 * In some cases when the iteration order isn't important, iteration over
 * arrays is trivial.  This is the case when:
 *   * The array has 0 or 1 dimensions.
 *   * The array is C or Fortran contiguous.
 * Use of an iterator can be skipped when this occurs.  These macros assist
 * in detecting and taking advantage of the situation.  Note that it may
 * be worthwhile to further check if the stride is a contiguous stride
 * and take advantage of that.
```

So, we see that a `ufunc` with contiguous arguments can be evaluated by a single call to the fast inner loop, completely bypassing the outer loop.

To appreciate the difference in complexity and overhead have a look at functions `trivial_two/three_operand_loop` vs `iterator_loop` in numpy/core/src/umath/ufunc_object.c and all the `npyiter_iternext_*` functions in numpy/core/src/multiarray/nditer_templ.c

### Strided ufunc eval is more expensive than strided copy

from the autogenerated numpy/core/src/multiarray/lowlevel_strided_loops.c

```
/*
 * This file contains low-level loops for copying and byte-swapping
 * strided data.
 *
```

This file is almost a quarter million lines.

By comparison the also autogenerated file numpy/core/src/umath/loops.c which provides ufunc innermost loops is a measly 15'000 lines.

This in itself suggests that copying may be more optimized than ufunc evaluation.

The relevant bit here are macros

```
/* Start raw iteration */
#define NPY_RAW_ITER_START(idim, ndim, coord, shape) \
        memset((coord), 0, (ndim) * sizeof(coord[0])); \
        do {

[...]

/* Increment to the next n-dimensional coordinate for two raw arrays */
#define NPY_RAW_ITER_TWO_NEXT(idim, ndim, coord, shape, \
                              dataA, stridesA, dataB, stridesB) \
            for ((idim) = 1; (idim) < (ndim); ++(idim)) { \
                if (++(coord)[idim] == (shape)[idim]) { \
                    (coord)[idim] = 0; \
                    (dataA) -= ((shape)[idim] - 1) * (stridesA)[idim]; \
                    (dataB) -= ((shape)[idim] - 1) * (stridesB)[idim]; \
                } \
                else { \
                    (dataA) += (stridesA)[idim]; \
                    (dataB) += (stridesB)[idim]; \
                    break; \
                } \
            } \
        } while ((idim) < (ndim))
```

which are used by function `raw_array_assign_array` in numpy/core/src/multiarray/array_assign_array.c which does the actual copying for the Python `ndarray.copy` method.

We can see that the overhead of "raw iteration" is rather modest compared to "full iteration" as used by ufuncs.

Comment: Thanks for these pointers, I will have to take a bit of time to get my head around exactly what's going on there. Under "Strided ufunc evaluation has significant overhead" it says that this can be skipped with contiguous arrays, and my array is C contiguous so I'm not sure that applies here

Comment: @roganjosh To be honest I just assumed that because of user2357112's post. I wouldn't rule out a similar effect happening at where even though it doesn't seem to be a proper ufunc.

Comment: @roganjosh Re the contiguity: No, that's very important: once you slice any but the zeroth dimension the resulting array is no longer contiguous.

Comment: @roganjosh Perhaps your intuition is right and only your terminology is off: consistent strides you will get, but contiguous means more than that, it also means no gaps. Obviously, anything you slice away will leave gaps.

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood your clarification sorry. I assumed that you were saying that by taking the slice rather than applying to the whole array, I was losing the advantage of the underlying array being contiguous and was hitting some overhead that wasn't as trivial as I imagined. This all just points to me needing to get better at understanding C - I'll stop pestering you now :)